# What is the best way to visualize my small c programs using some type of diagrams?

Tags: c#, c++, uml, visualization, diagram

I want to learn how can I visualize my small c programs using some type of diagrams . My programs generally include (3 or 4 functions) (some loops) (basic i/o (printf scanf)), and basic calculations.  I do not want to visualize everything about my program(name of vars, type of vars) , but I want to create some type of diagram which will help other person to understand how it works .Instead of showing 150-250 lines of code I want to show 1-2 page schema.

**Things I want to show (which I do not know how to show):**

- Inputs and Outputs (printf, scanf)
- Loops
- Control Statements

Also, I am looking for agreed and standart way of doing this .

Comment: If I were the audience, I'd prefer the code over anything else.

Comment: No matter what you do, it is impossible to visualize something that has no physical representation. The best you can hope for is some semblance of the flow of control. Try do diagram a relationship, and you will see where I am going with this.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, choosing the correct type of diagram would depend on what you want to show, but if you want other people to "understand how it works", I believe that a [flow chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) will suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

UML was all the rage a decade ago. It defines a bewildering number of diagram types, one of which is the "Activity diagram". It is a standard for drawing diagrams that show the things you want to show. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activity_diagram for an example and links.

I would definitely prefer code or pseudo-code over a diagram though. I think most people who are used to reading code would.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Visual Studio 2010, certain versions come with a flurry of tools to do this, here is one of the earlier articles [outlining](http://ajdotnet.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/visual-studio-2010-architecture-edition/) some features.

Answer (score 0):

You can compile the program with [gcc's gprof profiling options](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_80.html) and then convert the output of the run to a visual call graph using a tool like [Gprof2Dot](http://code.google.com/p/jrfonseca/wiki/Gprof2Dot).

While this isn't quite the level of detail you're hoping for it's probably the best you can do.  I've always found it to be a useful way of getting to know an unfamiliar code base.

Answer (score 0):

There are many software visualization tools available.  Check 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_visualization 
for a summary.  I like Enterprise Architect from Sparx Systems.  It's under $200 and is a full-featured UML tool that allows round-tripping your code and models.